# Scripting solution needed

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I have a written a script named **phone4** like the following:

```
# #!/bin/bash

  name=$1

  if ["$name" = ""]

  then echo -n "Enter a name to search for: "

        read name

  fi


  grep -i $name ~uli101/2017c/phonebook
```

but now i want to make some change in the script so that if I use the command **phone4 xyz** if no matching name is found, an appropriate message is displayed: "Name 'xyz' not in directory".

I want to use an 'if' statement to check the value of $? to see if the grep command was successful (remember, '0' indicates success).
If the grep is NOT successful, then echo the message (which includes the value of $name).

Make sure this works with both command line arguments and with a name read in from the user, and I need to use the message
EXACTLY as "Name 'xyz' not in directory". 
can anyone help me regarding this?

Comment: This looks like homework to me.

Comment: You must be mistaken in the site. We are here for free. "Script solution needed" seems a good post for upwork, there they are paid.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as too broad because it's asking for extra code to provide new functionality rather than seeking help with a specific problem.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you know how to write an if statement, you have one in your script.

Now, you should google to see how to compare `$?` to `0`, and put that in your if statement. `$?` should NOT match `0`.

Then you, you need to `echo "Name 'xyz' not in directory"` if `$?` is NOT `0`. How can you replace 'xyz' with `$name` ? Should be obvious, right ?

This really reads like an assignment of some kind ... yes, I could write a complete answer, but that would NOT help you.

> Give a man a fish, you feed him for the day, teach a man HOW to fish,
>   you feed him for life.

Comment: This user posts **[nothing but homework questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/199195/masum-billah)** so this is the best answer you could give him!